# python socket not accepting connections after certian about of time

Tags: python, sockets

My Python server stops accepting connections after a few minutes of receiving no data. To resolve this I've implemented a watchdog that basically restarts everything, but I would prefer to get to the bottom of the issue:

```
import os
import socket


class MyClass:

    ...

    def socket_server(self): 
        cwd = os.getcwd().replace("\\","/") + "/"  
        BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        try:
            self.ssFT = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.ssFT.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.ssFT.bind((socket.gethostname(), 51002))
            self.c.util.fprint('host=' + socket.gethostname() + '   port=' + str(51002))
            self.ssFT.listen(10)
        
        except:
            self.c.kill_all_threads  = True 
            self.c.util.fprint('Socket bind failed - restarting')
        
        while self.c.kill_all_threads == False:
        ...
            (conn, address) = self.ssFT.accept()
            print(conn, address)
        ...
```

Comment: what kind of exception is raised that you're catching there?

Comment: the try and except was for a binding issue that i had, but i am not receiving any errors for the .accept() when it stops accepting connections

Comment: what is `self.c`? (what is this class inheriting from?)

Comment: I have this code sitting in a class that is then called by the main program

Comment: Either `kill_all_threads` has become `true` or there was an exception, or you are reading from the accepted socket in the same thread and the peer isn't sending anything. More information requried.